# Form not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, forms

This form code is working in Mozilla and Chrome, but in Internet Explorer it is not working.

```
<form method="post" action="logincheck.php" >
    <span class="meta">
        <table>
    </span>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="meta">
                <label >Username </label>
            </span>
            <label>
        </td>
        <td> <input name="username" type="text" />
            </label>
</form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <label ><span class="meta">Password</td>
        <td>
            <input name="password" type="password" />
                     </span>
             </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="meta">
            </span>
            <label>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"  class="submit"/>
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: What is wrong? What should happen and when?

Comment: what is a working form code and what is a non working form code? Display, Php call, Submit button ?

Comment: it is working perfectly in mozilla , chrome. in internet explorer submit button doesnt responds at all.

Submit Buton is not working

Comment: That's because you're closing the form (`</form>` tag) before you add the submit button. Fix your nesting and element order!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a number of HTML errors, most important being an extra `</form>` tag shortly after the first `<input>`. That means the second `input` and the `submit` button are outside the form, so it won't work. Firefox and Chrome are being a bit more forgiving here it seems.

Fix your HTML and the form should work fine.

Answer (score 5):

You have [errors that automated QA tools can detect](http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<form method="post" action="logincheck.php">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input name="username" type="text" />
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input name="password" type="password" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"  class="submit" />
</form>
```

The correct code for this form must look like this.

- You do not need the table, you can style the form with easily with CSS over selecting the label & input fields

Answer (score 0):

> `<span class="meta">`
>      `<table>`
>     `</span>`

The nesting is wrong. In fact, there's a lot more wrong. Try googling what `<label>` does exactly, and what `<span>` does and when you want to use it. You probably want something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="logincheck.php" >
  <table>   
    <tr>
      <td><label class="meta">Username </label></td>
      <td><input name="username" type="text" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><label class="meta">Password</td>
      <td><input name="password" type="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"  class="submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>   
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

One first error is:

```
<span class="meta">
<table>   
</span>
```

But you have many errors.

Open and close tags as you will do with parenthesis. No horse riding. HTML and now XHTML need you to be a little bit more conscientious.

usefull tool:

- http://giminik.developpez.com/xhtml/
- http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version without span tags, label and extra `</form>` in the middle of the table before submit button.

I guess, you added those by hands in plain text editors.

```
<form method="post" action="logincheck.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Username
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="username" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="password" type="password" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```