# input outside of form enter key does not trigger submit only on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a form and an input outside of the form. The input is linked to the form.

I have tested this on Chrome and it works but on IE it does not.

Is this a known bug? Is there a link to the bug? PS: I don't need a solution I just need a confirmation that only IE behaves like this and perhaps a page where the bug is described or maybe a page where it says that it is function as design.

UPDATE

The bug that I am referring is this: When you enter some text on this input and press enter key I would expect for the form to submit. (as state previously on chrome it works as expected while on IE it does not)

Here is a code: go to the second input and press enter: In Chrome/Firefox/Opera the message submit called is displayed while in IE/Edge it does not.

```js
function submitForm(e) {
  alert('Submit called');
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form onsubmit="submitForm()" id="bugForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
  <hr>
  <input type="text" name="another" id="another" form="bugForm" />

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a page where indeed an input outside of a form is not supported (HTML5).

http://html5test.com/

Comment: If you think that you had got the answer for your question from that link than I suggest you to mark your own solution as an accepted answer for this question after 24 hrs may help other community members in future in similar kind of questions. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You did not posted your sample code, So we cannot accurately say what you are doing in your code and why it is not working in IE.

If we assume like you have any input tag outside your form and you want to submit a form by pressing enter key on that input control than it should not submit the form because it is not inside the form tag. In that way IE is working correctly and it should not consider as a bug.

If you have a requirement to do that than you can try to refer an example below will work with IE.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form  action="something.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<hr>
You can click this ->
<label for="submitButton">Submit</label><br> 
Or You can click ->
<input type="submit" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" />


</body>
</html>
```

For Reference, You can refer links below.

(1) [Form not working in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005015/form-not-working-in-internet-explorer)

(2) [Submit form using a button outside the  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag/12567605)

Comment: Indeed I forgot to mention the question from the title. I do not have a problem with the submission because that works. My problem is with the enter key on the input field outside the form but attached to the form

Comment: Please try to post your code to test the issue on our side.